# nginx upstream duplicate upstream

Tags: nginx

I use the scene is like this:

www.a.com.conf

```
……
upstream a_cluster_backend {
    server   1.1.1.1:80 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
    server   1.1.1.2:80 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
}
……
location / {
    proxy_pass http://a_cluster_backend;
}
```

www.b.mi.com.conf

```
……
upstream b_cluster_backend {
    server   1.1.1.1:80 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
    server   1.1.1.2:80 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
}
……
location / {
    proxy_pass http://b_cluster_backend;
}
```

Every time I down a server at the same time, to change the above two configuration files, I want to have hosts independent, then the two configuration file include, so that each line of a file can be modified only.
Like this:

www.a.com.conf

```
……
include vhosts/cluster.ini;
……
location / {
    proxy_pass http://cluster_backend;
}
```

www.b.mi.com.conf

```
……
include vhosts/cluster.ini;
……
location / {
    proxy_pass http://cluster_backend;
}
```

cluster.ini

```
upstream cluster_backend {
    server   1.1.1.1:80 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
    server   1.1.1.2:80 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;  
    }
```

In fact, this is not enough, it will prompt does not support, as follows:

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "cluster_backend" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhosts/cluster.ini:1
configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

Ask, in this scene I do more convenient, just want to put the Hosts independent, for more vhosts to include. so I vhosts use at the same time a number of machines, a down server, only need to modify a vhosts file

Answer (score 0):

Has been resolved
Added support for include code in upstream, compile

```
 306 static ngx_command_t  ngx_http_upstream_commands[] = {
 307
 308     { ngx_string("upstream"),
 309                  NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF|NGX_CONF_BLOCK|NGX_CONF_TAKE1,
 310       ngx_http_upstream,
 311       0,
 312       0,
 313       NULL },
 + 314     { ngx_string("include"),
 + 315       NGX_HTTP_UPS_CONF|NGX_CONF_TAKE1,
 + 316       ngx_conf_include,
 + 317       0,
 + 318       0,
 + 319       NULL },
 320
 321     { ngx_string("server"),
 322       NGX_HTTP_UPS_CONF|NGX_CONF_1MORE,
 323       ngx_http_upstream_server,
 324       NGX_HTTP_SRV_CONF_OFFSET,
 325       0,
 326       NULL },
 327
 328       ngx_null_command
 329 };
```

See : http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/attachment/ticket/635/upstream-include.patch